# Pangrams python implementation

Tags: python, programming-challenge

Given

> Roy wanted to increase his typing speed for programming contests. So, his friend advised him to type the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" repeatedly, because it is a pangram. (Pangrams are sentences constructed by using every letter of the alphabet at least once.)
>   After typing the sentence several times, Roy became bored with it. So he started to look for other pangrams. Given a sentence s, tell Roy if it is a pangram or not. Input Format Input consists of a line containing s.

Constraints

> Length of s can be at most 103 \$(1≤|s|≤103)\$ and it may contain spaces, lower case and upper case letters. Lower case and upper case instances of a letter are considered the same.

Solution 1

```
from collections import defaultdict
import string

def is_pangram(astr):
    lookup = defaultdict(int)

    for char in astr:
        lookup[char.lower()] += 1        
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if lookup[char] == 0:
            return False
    return True

print "pangram" if is_pangram(raw_input()) else "not pangram"
```

Solution 2

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def is_pangram(astr):
    counter = Counter(astr.lower())
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if counter[char] == 0:
            return False
    return True

print "pangram" if is_pangram(raw_input()) else "not pangram"
```

Which is better in terms of running time and space complexity?

Comment: Have you benchmarked them? What did it say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you do not actually need the count of each character, it would be simpler to use a `set` and the superset operator `>=`:

```
def is_pangram(astr):
    return set(astr.lower()) >= set(string.ascii_lowercase):
```

---

Your two solutions are almost identical, though here

```
for char in astr:
    lookup[char.lower()] += 1
```

it would be faster to lowercase the whole string at once (like you already do in solution 2):

```
for char in astr.lower():
    lookup[char] += 1
```

Other than that, the only difference is `defaultdict` vs. `Counter`. The latter makes your code more elegant, but since the standard library implements `Counter` in pure Python, there may be a speed advantage to `defaultdict`.

Comment: Two things, you say Counter is faster than defaultdict, right? Second, you say that lowercasing whole string is faster but why?

Comment: What is the significance of the maximum length `103` on the string.

Comment: Got the answer, defaultdict is implemented in `c` hence its faster than `Counter`.

Comment: @CodeYogi A single call to the `lower` method is faster than many calls of the same, especially because the actual lowercasing of each string happens in a fast C loop. I don't know where the 103 comes from, but Google tells me that there is a Guinness world record for typing 103 characters with the nose: http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2015/9/spotlight-fastest-typing-with-the-nose-394753

Comment: Hmm, strange (for the record part)!

Answer (score 3):

This one requires only one integer of storage:

```
    ord_a = 97 # ord('a')
    ord_z = 122 # ord('z')

    def is_pangram(s):
      found = 0
      for c in s:
        ord_char = ord(c.lower())
        if ord_a <= ord_char <= ord_z:
          found |= 1 << (ord_char - ord_a)
      return found == (1 << 26) - 1
```

The data structure used is the integer `found`, whose least significant 26 bits are used to indicate if the corresponding letter has been found. The coding is simply a=0, b=1, etc, which can be conveniently done obtained from the ASCII code as `ord(char) - ord('a')`. The characters in the string have to be iterated, if you wish you could stop when you found them all.

Note that even though the algorithmic complexity is essentially the lowest possible, the fact that the loop is in pure Python makes it slower than one which avoids looping in Python, even if it has to perform more operations.

Answer (score 2):

Both are too slow since you don't need to care about the amount but you're storing a count of each letter anyway. You just need to know if all of the relevant characters are in the string. You can do this easier, faster and with less memory usage by calling `all`.

```
def is_pangram(astr):
    return all(char in astr.lower() for char in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

This will just check each character in `ascii_lowercase` and see if it's in `astr`. No need to store values at all, and this supports shortcircuiting. Short circuiting will prematurely end a test if it realises that it already has its result.

So the script will run through and might find an a, b, c, d, and e. But then maybe it can't find an f in the string, instead of continuing to check for g it will immediately return `False` at that point because it already knows that one letter is missing, so the expression *can't* be `True`. This saves on time since the rest of the checks are redundant for the result you want.

Comment: What do you mean by `shortcircuiting`? can you please explain me a bit?

Comment: @CodeYogi I added an explanation, let me know if it's not quite clear enough!

Comment: Hmm, there is something wrong, for each letter it will do the linear search in `ascii_lowercase` so, it seems to be slow.

Comment: @CodeYogi I'm running benchmarks and that's not what I've found. My answer seems seven times faster than both yours, have you tested it? It's also even faster if you make the string a `set` as @JanneKarila suggested.

Comment: No, but logically I am correct. Now its a totally different story how the language has implemented its operations internally. And most of the time we first solve the problem on paper before typing it down.

Comment: @CodeYogi Logically constant look ups are bad, but also so is creating unnecessary data, not implementing short circuiting and using slower functions. `all` is usually fast as it runs in `C` instead of Python. Most importantly, actual testing is more important than following conceptual design patterns, because it always varies in practice.

Comment: @CodeYogi in fact it iterates over ascii_lowercase, and it does a search in astr.lower(). In the worst case it would indeed iterate the string 26 times.

Comment: Okay, just clarifying where we are saving memory here? in my case I was storing whole input string and the `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: Your original solution has a dictionary with keys for all the characters and values holding their counts, my solution just checks for the existence of each character and results in a single boolean.